# Getting 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage' is ambiguous error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Iam working in an mvc 2 Rc project.It was working fine until today morning.In the morning i got an error message.

Parser Error Message: The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage' is ambiguous: it could come from assembly 'C:\Intersight\IntersightWeb\bin\IntersightWeb.DLL' or from assembly 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll'. Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.

[image]

But in the previous execution it was ok.I tried to fix the above issues in many ways.Please help me to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of reasons for that error.

> My typical solution for this is : Open
>   your references, go to the properties
>   of System.Web.Mvc and check whether
>   Copy Local is True. If so, try setting
>   it to False and delete the DLL from
>   the bin folder, then Ctrl-F5 again.

Other Fixes:

1. You can set referenced assemblies
   to not be copied to the bin folder
   (right click on the reference and
   select properties)
2. Maybe your references points to
   old dll. You can fix this with open
   the project using Visual Studio, and
   in Solution Explorer, expand the
   References node. Delete the
   reference to System.Web.Mvc (which
   points to the version 1.0 assembly).
   Add a reference to System.Web.Mvc
   (v2.0.0.0).
3. Uninstall mvc and reinstall
   it. [Download MVC2 RC](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/39978)